# Why can't I write the character 台 in my pinyin input method?

Tags: characters, writing, input-methods

I'm on Linux and using Sunpinyin and Linpinyin input methods. In both, when I input "tai" I never get any suggestion of the character that I somethimes want: 台. I must be doing something wrong, but what? How do I write 台?

When I try to input it I get all other characters "tai" but not 台. I'm on Xubuntu 16.04 and using a `libpinyin` based input method in `fcitx`.

---

I changed to iBus input method with "Intelligent pinyin" and there everything works as expected with "tai". Seems like it might be a bug in the version of Fcitx that's in the Debian repository.

Comment: So what pops up? A list of words that have the pinyin "tai" except 台?

Comment: @Blaszard Good point, you're correct, that's what happens. See my edit above.

Comment: I'm using sogou pinyin on Ubuntu 16.04, you may find it here: https://pinyin.sogou.com/linux/

Comment: I recommend http://rime.im/ it supports ibus and fcitx. The best on linux.

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu 17.10, and using the Sunpinyin, it comes up right away as number 1 or 2: [image: IME output]

What is your particular Linux version?